# OCaml - Expression was expected of type 'b list

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether a set (denoted by a list) is a subset of another.

I already wrote a helper function that gives me the intersection:

```
let rec intersect_helper a b =
    match a, b with
    | [], _ -> []
    | _, [] -> []
    | ah :: at, bh :: bt ->
        if ah > bh then
            intersect_helper a bt
        else if ah < bh then
            intersect_helper at b
        else
            ah :: intersect_helper at bt
```

I'm trying to use this inside of the subset function (if A is a subset of B, then A = A intersect B):

```
let subset a_ b_ =
    let a = List.sort_uniq a_
    and b = List.sort_uniq b_
    in intersect_helper a b;;
```

> Error: This expression has type 'a list -> 'a list                                                                         but an expression was expected of type 'b list

What exactly is wrong here? I can use `intersect_helper` perfectly fine by itself, but calling it with lists here does not work. From what I know about `'a`, it's just a placeholder for the first argument type. Shouldn't the lists also be of type `'a list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you could solve your own problem, but your code seems exceedingly intricate to me.

If I understood correctly, you want a function that tells whether a list is a subset of another list. Put another way, you want to know **whether all elements of list `a` are present in list `b`**.

Thus, the signature of your function should be

```
val subset : 'a list -> 'a list -> bool
```

The standard library comes with a variety of functions to manipulate lists.

```
let subset l1 l2 =
  List.for_all (fun x -> List.mem x l2) l1
```

`List.for_all` checks that all elements in a list satisfy a given condition. `List.mem` checks whether a value is present in a list.

And there you have it. Let's check the results:

```
# subset [1;2;3] [4;2;3;5;1];;
- : bool = true

# subset [1;2;6] [4;2;3;5;1];;
- : bool = false

# subset [1;1;1] [1;1];; (* Doesn't work with duplicates, though. *)
- : bool = true
```

**Remark**: A tiny perk of using `List.for_all` is that it is a [short-circuit operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That means that it will stop whenever an item doesn't match, which results in better performance overall.

---

Also, since you specifically asked about sets, the standard library has a module for them. However, sets are a bit more complicated to use because they need you to create new modules using a functor.

```
module Int = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end

module IntSet = Set.Make(Int)
```

The extra overhead is worth it though, because now IntSet can use the whole [`Set`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html) interface, which includes the `IntSet.subset` function.

```
# IntSet.subset (IntSet.of_list [1;2;3]) (IntSet.subset [4;2;3;5;1]);;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: Remark: although `List.for_all` is a short-circuit operator it is still O(n) in worst-case, so your implementation of the subset function is O(nm), or in general O(n^2). The same is true for sorted lists, in the worst case they will require O(nm) comparisons, e.g., `[1;2;3;4]` vs `[1;2;3;5]`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to learn ocaml for a class, and this was one of the exercises. I'm well aware that there is probably a library available for the set data structure. Thank you though! I upvoted.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay if you found this answer the best one, please accept it so others can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let a = List.sort_uniq a_
```

Should instead call:

```
let a = List.sort_uniq compare a_
```